# Text isn't above transparent bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a div above a transparent colored bar, but even with the bar having a lower z-index, the div appears above it.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div id='bar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: black;
}
#foo {
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
}
#bar {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height:100%;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/XjncA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `z-index` only works if `position` is different than `static` (*).

You can fix it with `position: relative`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XjncA/2/)

---

(*) According with http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index,

> 'z-index'
>
>   Value:    auto |  | inherit
>   Initial:      auto
>   **Applies to:     positioned elements**
>   Inherited:    no
>   Percentages:      N/A
>   Media:    visual
>   Computed value:   as specified

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/XjncA/1/

You need to add the following style to #foo:

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
}
```